# Howto make an element fill what's left of a layout

Tags: android, layout, coding-style

So far I have this layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="text" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What do people do when they have a layout like this where the middle TextView should fill what's left of the layout?  Here I have an ImageView that is 40dip wide and a TextView that also is 40dip wide.  So I'm trying to get the middle TextView to fill up what's left.  The code above is as far as I get.  I got the middle TextView to fill up what's left and some extra - leaving the left ImageView to be smaller than the 40dip I've set it to be.

What do I do here?  Layouting in Android is not easy.

What I'm trying to do is create a list looking like the lists in Market.  With an icon to the left, two lines of text in the middle, and som extra information to the right.  Are there any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following layout will give you what you want :

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">   

<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Stretched text"
        />

    <TextView
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="LeftOver"
        />  
</TableRow>
```

If you want to continue working with a LinearLayout, you'll need to use the gravity properties. The following will also give you what you want :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:background="#dddddd" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Stretched Text" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, checkout the [view - API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html) for several layout examples.

Comment: Thanx! I see now what the trick is. Only setting layout_weight on the element that should be stretched. I had it on all three elements.